# Should we always update model when view changes in React

Tags: reactjs

React is one-way binding and it is up to developers to decide how to update the model upon a fired event, e.g.:

`<input type="checkbox" checked={item.complete} onChange={handleItemClick} />`

The question is should we alway update the model as best practice no matter what?

Comment: I guess it's not clear to me what exactly you have in mind by the qualifiers "always" and "no matter what".  If there's an update to be made to state then I don't see why one wouldn't perform that update.  Perhaps you have a specific example in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to familiarise yourself with state. See the useState docs:  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html